# Test data for neo4j

Tags: testing, junit, neo4j, dbunit

Is there a nice and clean mechanism out of the box which can be used to populate a test instance of neo4j. I'm looking for something similar to DBUnit. I'm imagining an xml file which is then sucked in to populate neo4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily load a GraphML file, see for instance http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/gremlin-plugin.html#rest-api-load-a-sample-graph

Also, you could have a template populated datastore that you point your database engine at.

Thirdly, in neo4j itself we are using annotation-based test harnesses, so you can do

@Graph("I know you")

To create a sample graph, see https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/kernel/src/test/java/org/neo4j/metatest/TestJavaTestDocsGenerator.java#L117
(original link: https://github.com/neo4j/community/blob/master/kernel/src/test/java/org/neo4j/metatest/TestJavaTestDocsGenerator.java#L107)

Comment: Thanks. I saw this quite late. I actually ended up creating something very similar to dbunit. The xml is actually similar to the example you provided.

Answer (score 2):

You may check out mirko's wikipedia data import solution which builds up  a graph database containing 9,006,704 nodes (pages, titles only) and 82,537,500 relationships (links) as he mentions => http://www.encodedknowledge.com/2012/02/neo4j-wikipedia-graph/